# как привязать WebChromeClient к WebView?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://tut.by/");
    }
    public class SimpleWebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {
        private Activity activity = null;

    }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebChromeClient(android.webkit.WebChromeClient)

Comment: если б мне там все понятно было - вопрос не задавал бы

Comment: ну привязать это setWebChromeClient() а его реализация - на ваше усмотрение. можно передать дефолтный, а можно свой кастомный

Answer (score 0):

Здесь надо заменить:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

на:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new SimpleWebViewClientImpl());
```

Comment: Поменял, но теперь он просто поверх WebView запускает отдельный браузер. А как , что бы внутри WebView (в той же активити)?

Comment: @Магатрон3000 Эм а зачем ты тогда вообще ставишь кастомный WebViewClient? Может тебе не его надо, а WebChromeClient? Это разные вещи.